# Why does JMH shows the same results for different implementations?

Tags: java, jvm, jmh

JMH shows the same results for different methods no matter whether those methods contain any code or not.

Example 1: empty method to be tested

```
public class MyBenchmark {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(args);
    }

    @Fork(value = 1, warmups = 0)
    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    @Warmup(iterations = 5)
    public String run() {
        return "done";
    }
}
```

The result of running this code is 1e-8 s/op.

Example 2: method with some work to do:

```
public class MyBenchmark {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(args);
    }

    private static List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    @Fork(value = 1, warmups = 0)
    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    @Warmup(iterations = 5)
    public String run() {
        List<Integer> copy = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Integer item : list) {
            copy.add(item);
        }
        return "done";
    }
}
```

The result is the same: 1e-8 s/op.

So, the benchmark is clearly not working. What might be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an incorrect time scale - seconds per operations. It seems too big for your no op test. Just add the following parameter `@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)` to your test:

```
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MyBenchmark {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(args);
    }

    @Fork(value = 1, warmups = 0)
    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    @Warmup(iterations = 5)
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
    public String run() {
        return "done";
    }
}
```

with following result:

```
# Run complete. Total time: 00:00:25

Benchmark        Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
MyBenchmark.run  avgt   20  5.390 ± 0.264  ns/op
```

Regarding to your second example, it contains almost all possible issues/pitfalls:

- dead code elimintaion - JVM is smart enough to detect loop without side effects and remove it from method body.
- wrong measurement
- incorrect initialization - JMH has special annotations `Setup` and `State` for proper benchmark initialization

Here is a "correct" version of your example(I just removed oblivious mistakes):

```
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@Fork(value = 1)
public class MyBenchmark {

    private List<Integer> list;

    @Setup
    public void init() {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    @Warmup(iterations = 5)
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
    public Object run() {
        List<Integer> copy = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Integer item : list) {
            copy.add(item);
        }
        return copy;
    }
}
```

with latency:

```
# Run progress: 0.00% complete, ETA 00:00:25
# Fork: 1 of 1
# Warmup Iteration   1: 2488116493.000 ns/op
# Warmup Iteration   2: 201271178.600 ns/op
```

In order to understand all possible issues with microbenchmarking please read [the following examples](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/25d8b2695bac/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples).

Comment: Does it make any difference when you put any actual work inside this method? Cause it seams not to be working. In my case empty method works even longer then the "heavy" one...